# Possible to use modal editing inside Vim's command-line mode?

Tags: command-line, vim

Vim's normal and insert modes are wonderful. A source of constant frustration for me is that whenever I enter command-line mode for entering Ex commands (by pressing `:`) suddenly I lose all the niceness of modal editing and wind up with a set of totally different (and comparatively lame) shortcuts that don't correspond to normal-mode OR insert-mode. Is there any way to enable standard modal editing of ex commands on the Vim command line?
This would also be nice for / searching, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim actually has several modes, of which normal and insert are just the most obvious. So to say...

To enter the command-line window from command-line mode (the mode you're in after you press `:`), press `Ctrl-F`. Now you're in the command-line window, where you can write up a command just like in insert, and edit it kinda like in normal mode. Enter will execute the command.

An example:

```
press : ("to get into" cmdline)
press Ctrl-F
press a
write echom "Hello world!"
press Esc
press Enter
```

It will echo' the "Hello world!" on the commandline, just like as if you've written that command from the cmdline.

*Does this make any sense?*

Comment: You can also get to the "Command-line window" by typing `q:`. If you want the same thing for searching, `q/` and `q?` are analogous. `Ctrl-F` also works in the middle of a `/` or `?` search. To see the full documentation, run `:help cmdline-window` in vim.

Comment: @MikeSep - Good point! I knew there were some other ways as well, but have gotten so used doing it this way, I couldn't remember what they were. Thanks for adding that up!

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'd upvote if I could. :)